# Cannot build react-native app on xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, react-native, build-error

I'm having some issues when I build my react-native app in XCode to test on app on my iPhone.

The 4 errors are:

> - Expected identifier
> - Expected identifier or '('
> - Missing context for method declaration
> - '@end' must appear in an Object-C context

All of these errors are in my project's test .m file 3rsTests.m

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>

#import <React/RCTLog.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

#define TIMEOUT_SECONDS 600
#define TEXT_TO_LOOK_FOR @"Welcome to React Native!"

@interface threeRsTests : XCTestCase

@end

@implementation 3RsTests //Error: Expected Identifier

- (BOOL)findSubviewInView:(UIView *)view matching:(BOOL(^)(UIView *view))test
{
  if (test(view)) {
    return YES;
  }
  for (UIView *subview in [view subviews]) {
    if ([self findSubviewInView:subview matching:test]) {
      return YES;
    }
  }
  return NO;
}

- (void)testRendersWelcomeScreen //Error: missing context for method declaration
{
  UIViewController *vc = [[[RCTSharedApplication() delegate] window] rootViewController];
  NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:TIMEOUT_SECONDS];
  BOOL foundElement = NO;

  __block NSString *redboxError = nil;
  RCTSetLogFunction(^(RCTLogLevel level, RCTLogSource source, NSString *fileName, NSNumber *lineNumber, NSString *message) {
    if (level >= RCTLogLevelError) {
      redboxError = message;
    }
  });

  while ([date timeIntervalSinceNow] > 0 && !foundElement && !redboxError) {
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1]];
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1]];

    foundElement = [self findSubviewInView:vc.view matching:^BOOL(UIView *view) {
      if ([view.accessibilityLabel isEqualToString:TEXT_TO_LOOK_FOR]) {
        return YES;
      }
      return NO;
    }];
  }

  RCTSetLogFunction(RCTDefaultLogFunction);

  XCTAssertNil(redboxError, @"RedBox error: %@", redboxError);
  XCTAssertTrue(foundElement, @"Couldn't find element with text '%@' in %d seconds", TEXT_TO_LOOK_FOR, TIMEOUT_SECONDS);
}

@end //Error: '@end' must appear in an Objective-C context
```

I'm not a Swift or Object-C programmer so these errors are quite cryptic to me. I'd appreciate if anyone can give me a hand on how to get my code to compile.

Comment: You generally shouldn't have numbers in names as it cause issues like this, I suggest replacing the name and then see if the errors remain

Comment: please, paste your actual code, instead of photo of them

Comment: Thanks for the advice @EzizDurdyyev. I didn't paste code because you would not be able to see the errors if I did.

Comment: You can add a comment with the error. Photos of code are a big no-no around here.

Answer (score 0):

This was a test file of sort and does not affect the way the name appears to the user. I followed [@David Liaw's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1322878/david-liaw) advice and renamed the identifier at line 17 and the app completed its built 100%